# Cell fracture, shadow gap problem

Tags: animation, cell-fracture

I'm trying to do a cell fracture to an object in order to destroy with an animation. My point is that, I would want to don't see the fracture line before the object get destroyed. For istance, is there a way to reduce the leftovere bewtween the fracture lines as in the image?
[image]

Comment: Cell fracture has no such feature. You have two options ... animate visibility for render (unbreaked/breaked object) by keyframe in Outliner or download special build of Blender (probably not available for latest versions) with Fracture Modifier that keeps object compact until break is calculated (super useful for shatter glass).

Comment: Thank  you for repaly, I think this method should work for me, I checked and the last version with the Fracture modifier is the 2.8, still a bit old but not really. I've seen some video and is a really nice feature

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to have your unfractured object invisible, then at the time of fracture swap it with the fractured object.

A trickier solution would be in Edit Mode, box select each nearby group of vertices with <kbd>B</kbd>, then press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale them and move your cursor toward them to move them together, like so:

[image]

The goal is to get the vertices near each other into the exact same position as the vertices from each object.

When you've done all the vertices, the edges are much less visible in renders:

[image]

Comment: ... yes, but taking vertices at the same place will result in explosion at the first frame of Rigid Body simulation :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very smart I haven't tought at that, but for my object could be a slow process. Since is my very first time I'm simulation, how the other software solve that? Beacuse is a problem.

Comment: You could manually animate them for that initial break until they're far enough away, then simulate from there. At that point though it's probably easier to just swap between non-broken and broken on impact, and simulate from there.